# Memory layout of 2D area

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-management

How is a 2D area layout in memory? Especially if its a staggered area. Given, to my understanding, that memory is contiguous going from Max down to 0, does the computer allocate each area in the area one after the other? If so, should one of the areas in the area need to be resized, does it shift all the other areas down as to make space for the newly sized area?

If specifics are needed:

C++17/14/11

Clang

linux x86

Revision: (thanks user4581301)

I'm referring to having a `vector<vector<T>>` where `T` is some defined type. I'm not talking template programming here unless that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are we talking C++'s view of the memory; the OS's view of the memory or the physical address of the memory?  Each of the above has a different idea about how memory is laid out and addressed.

Comment: Would the differences in memory there be completely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precise details of how `std::vector` is implemented will vary from compiler to compiler, but more than likely, a `std::vector` contains a `size_t` member that stores the length and a pointer to the storage.  It allocates this storage using whatever allocator you specify in the template, but the default is to use `new`, which allocates them off the heap.  You probably know this, but typically the heap is the area of RAM below the stack in memory, which grows from the bottom up as the stack grows from the top down, and which the runtime manages by tracking which blocks of it are free.

The storage managed by a `std::vector`is a contiguous array of objects, so a vector of twenty vectors of `T` would contain at least a `size_t` storing the value 20, and a pointer to an array of twenty structures each containing a length and a pointer.  Each of those pointers would point to an array of `T`, stored contiguously in memory.

If you instead create a rectangular two-dimensional array, such as `T table[ROWS][COLUMNS]`, or a `std::array< std::array<T, COLUMNS>, ROWS >`, you will instead get a single continuous block of T elements stored in row-major order, that is: all the elements of row 0, followed by all the elements of row 1, and so on.

If you know the dimensions of the matrix in advance, the rectangular array will be more efficient because you’ll only need to allocate one block of memory. This is faster because you’ll only need to call the allocator and the destructor one time, instead of once per row, and also because it will be in one place, not split up over many different locations, and therefore the single block is more likely to be in the processor’s cache.

Answer (score 1):

`vector`s are thin wrappers around a dynamically allocated array of their elements. For a `vector<vector<T>>`, this means that the outer `vector`'s internal array contains the inner `vector` structures, but the inner `vector`s allocate and manage their own internal arrays separately (the structure contains a pointer to the managed array).

Essentially, the 2D aspect is purely in the program logic; the elements of any given "row" are contiguous, but there is no specified spacial relationship between the rows.

True 2D arrays (where the underlying memory is allocated as a single block) only really happen with C-style arrays declared with 2D syntax (`int foo[10][20];`) and nested `std::array` types, or POD types following the same basic design.

Comment: Related tangent: This lack of a spatial relationship can result in poor cache behaviour and surprisingly large hits to performance.

Comment: @user4581301: Yup. The main advantage is in the resizing case the OP mentioned, since the sizes of each `vector` are independent, and resizing one `vector` only has to move around the contents of that `vector`, not the whole 2D structure. Random access is slower, but resizing is faster and sizes can be independent for each row.